# Pandas, create new column based on other columns across multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the following dataframe representing the dietary habits of my pet frog

```
date       bugs_eaten_today
2019-01-31 0
2019-01-30 5
2019-01-29 6
2019-01-28 7
2019-01-27 2
...
```

Now I want to calculate a new column `bugs_eaten_past_20_days`

```
date       bugs_eaten_today bugs_eaten_paast_20_days
2019-01-31 0                48
2019-01-30 5                38
2019-01-29 6                57
2019-01-28 7                63
2019-01-27 2                21
...
```

How would I go about doing this? (Note that we don't have data for last 20 rows, so they will just be `NaN`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a rolling sum (with 20 rather than 3):

```
In [11]: df.bugs_eaten_today.rolling(3, 1).sum()
Out[11]:
0     0.0
1     5.0
2    11.0
3    18.0
4    15.0
Name: bugs_eaten_today, dtype: float64
```

You have to do this in reverse, since the index is reversed:

```
In [12]: df[::-1].bugs_eaten_today.rolling(3, 1).sum()
Out[12]:
4     2.0
3     9.0
2    15.0
1    18.0
0    11.0
Name: bugs_eaten_today, dtype: float64

In [13]: df['bugs_eaten_paast_20_days'] = df[::-1].bugs_eaten_today.rolling(3, 1).sum()
```

---

It's probably more robust to use date as the index and roll over 20D(ays):

```
In [21]: df1 = df.set_index('date').sort_index()

In [22]: df1.bugs_eaten_today.rolling('3D', 1).sum()
Out[22]:
date
2019-01-27     2.0
2019-01-28     9.0
2019-01-29    15.0
2019-01-30    18.0
2019-01-31    11.0
Name: bugs_eaten_today, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what if the column I want generated depended on a more complex function, as opposed to just a simple sum. Would there be a more general way to iterate through the dataframe with a sliding 20 unit window (looking either ahead or behind)?

Comment: @AlanSTACK There's rolling.apply which accepts a user's function (similar to DataFrame apply): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html

Comment: Thank you. Before I accept your answer, do you think you could provide an example of doing what you did in your response with rolling apply - so more novice users can quickly understand what to do?

Comment: @AlanSTACK something like `df1.bugs_eaten_today.rolling('3D', 1).apply(lambda x: x.sum(), raw=False)` (though that is a silly example, you can do whatever python function - takes a Series of those (upto) 20 rows.